# Unable to run development node after repo migration

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node

I tried running `cargo run -- --dev` after building. However i get this error `0: Invalid input: Error opening spec file` dev`: No such file or directory (os error 2)`.

I don't know rust and substrate however after slight debugging i found it to breaking at line https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/e38998801e433ecc569ff6d58d1d0aa80eaff771/polkadot/cli/src/command.rs#L149.

Variable named `path` is coming as `dev`.
If i directly pass spec json path (`polkadot/node/service/chain-specs/polkadot.json`) in the above line then it is able to fetch the spec but gives error unable to find binary in paths `/users/$NAME/blockchain/polkadot-sdk/target/debug` and `/usr/lib/polkadot`.

`` Error 0: Worker binaries could not be found, make sure polkadot was built/installed correctly. If you ran with `cargo run`, please run `cargo build` first. Searched given workers path (None), polkadot binary path ("/Users/$NAME/blockchain/polkadot-sdk/target/debug"), and lib path (/usr/lib/polkadot), workers names: None ``.

However the binary is present in the first path atleast. I cannot directly run a binary after downloading as i need to make some code changes and plug it to polkadot js apps.

[image: target folder screenshot]

Comment: Which binary do you want to run? `(parachain-)node-template`/`polkadot`?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas Polkadot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also run the binary directly from the path if you have built the code using `--release` then the binary would be in `/target/release/"bianry_name"` and you can run it via the command `./target/release/"bianry_name" --dev` .

And if you didn't built the code in `--release` than you binary will be in `/target/debug/"bianry_name"` and you can run it through command `./target/debug/"bianry_name" --dev`

Comment: I have also tried that and it gives me this error ```Error:
   0: Worker binaries could not be found, make sure polkadot was built/installed correctly. If you ran with `cargo run`, please run `cargo build` first. Searched given workers path (None), polkadot binary path ("/Users/rajdeepsingh/blockchain/polkadot-sdk/target/debug"), and lib path (/usr/lib/polkadot), workers names: None``` Have updated the original question with a screenshot of target folder and the binary exists

Answer (score 0):

This was an ongoing issue raised in polkadot-sdk repo. Answered there, linking here

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/1372#issuecomment-1725114216